# Segmentation fault: zsh: segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I get a segfault when I add (int filter) in the struct. Is it possible to fix?
Error message: **zsh: segmentation fault**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Student {
    char name[30];
    char surname[30];
    int course;                 // year of study
    double average;             // average grade
    
    int load;                   // number of courses
    char courses[10][30];       // course names
    int grades[10];             // course grades
    
    
    char languages[100];        // spoken languages
    
    int negative;
//    int filter;
} Student;



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *db = NULL;
    // open database file for reading, provide a parameter or use default "db.bin"
    if (argc > 1)
        db = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    else
        db = fopen("db.bin", "rb");
        
    if (db){                            
        Student students[1000];         // all the data goes here
        int size = 0;                   // how many students in database
        
        // reading data from file
        fread(&size, sizeof(int), 1, db);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){         
            fread(&students[i], sizeof(Student), 1, db);            
        }   
        printf("%d records loaded succesfully\n", size);
        
        
        // MODIFY CODE BELOW
        
        int counterDemo = 0; // for counting students

        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){ // process all the student records in database
            Student s = students[i]; // store data for each student in s
            s.negative = 0;
            // Checking if student has Philosophy and passed Philosophy exam
            for(int j = 0; j < s.load; ++j)
            {
                if(!strcmp(s.courses[j], "Philosophy"))
                {
                    s.negative++;
                }
                    
            }
            bool philosophy_exam = false;
            if(s.negative != 0)    // If student has Philosophy and passed Philosophy exam
            {
                philosophy_exam = true;
            }

            if(philosophy_exam){ // *** first filter, conditions on the student
                int anotherDemo = 0; // for counting courses/grades
                printf("%s %s %d %.2f %d ", s.name, s.surname, s.course, s.average, s.load); // print student data

                for (int i = 0; i < s.load; ++i){ // process each course taken by the student
                    if(1){ // *** second filter, conditions on the course/grade
                        ++anotherDemo; // counting courses
                        printf("%s %d ", s.courses[i], s.grades[i]);
                    }
                }
                printf("%s\n", s.languages);
                
                if (anotherDemo == s.load) // *** third filter, various other conditions            
                    ++counterDemo; // counting studfents
            }
        }
        printf("Filter applied, %d students found\n", counterDemo); // how many passed the filters
        fclose(db); 
    } else {
        printf("File db.bin not found, check current folder\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I commented the problematic variable out.
Also I run my code on terminal, like always. I am using (clang "file" -o main) could this be the problem? I have tried to run this code in different apps, but it doesn't help.

Comment: You're reading raw struct contents from a file, so if the struct doesn't have *exactly* the same layout, you're going to have problems.

Comment: **Always** check the return value from input functions to ensure they work as intended: here the value returned by `fread` must be 1. It won't be at some point (and the data won't align at all) because you are reading more data per struct than was saved in the file. If you want to read into a new struct then read into the old definition, copy the members to the new one, and set the value of the new member.

Comment: After the structure has been written to the file, you shouldn't change the layout of the structure and read from the same file.